# CSS Background-position relative to document not element?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if this is possible, the ability to set the background position of an image to the top left of the html document, not the top left of the element it's the background of.

Psuedo-code

```
body {
    background-image: url(someurlhere);
    background-position: top left;
}
element {
    background-image: url(sameurlhere);
    background-position: top left /*Relative to body not element*/;
}
```

If I need to provide anything else to this question let me know and I'll amend it, but I'm sure it's pretty straight forward.

Edit: I can't use absolute positioning, I'm loading dynamic content and I want a tiled image to fit the background of several elements to make the illusion of holes in the page.

Edit 2: Here are some pictures to better explain the problem.

Picture 1: Notice the repeated pattern in the header elements. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O87Gf.png

Picture 2:This variation is what I aim to achieve. https://i.stack.imgur.com/leBPg.png

Comment: Why not just place the background image on the body element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first question would be why you are not just setting the background image on the `body` element.

But if that's not appropriate, you have the option to set a background image on an element to `fixed`, in which case it will be fixed to the top left of the browser window and won't scroll.

```
element {background: url(image.fig) repeat fixed;}
```

However, the background will only show on the element it's attached to, even though it starts at the top left corner of the screen. (This is handy for parallax effects.)

EDIT: As a side note, if you are using the longhand background properties, `fixed` is set with

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I'm trying to achieve, I've added some images with a note to the question, I hope that helps to explain it better.

Comment: I don't see what you are gaining there. Are you trying to make the pattern consistent, so that it's as if there's one single background on the whole page? I think you could do that with my method, by putting the same background declaration on each element that needs the background.

Comment: Oh I see, the fixed applies to background-attachment not background-position. This does work, but you might need to clarify it for other people who may stumble across this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, good point. I've updated the post. I tend to think in shorthand, so often forget to mention the longhand version. Sorry for the confusion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wrap your element in a div absolute, and position it as you wish.

Comment: Editted the question a bit, sorry but absolute positioning isn't an option :).

Comment: How can this not be a possibility? Can I see a codepen or a live example?

Comment: I've got a live development of the site running at http://ruddev.com/ruddev/ I'm attempting to make the header bars work with the background to variate the pattern.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, you want to align the background of the header with the background?

Comment: Yea, I think that's how it should be explained.

Comment: The best way to achieve this is make your headers transparent. But I don't really see the point haha no one is ever going to notice.

Comment: The repeated pattern on all of the elements is surprisingly noticeable due to the nature of the tile being used, I agree it's not a major problem, but some people will notice and that's enough for me to try and find a solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more information on the context of the element? Does it have any positioning set? Where is it in the document? It's a little unclear to me what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Would putting the background on the body work?

This would set the background at the top left, but I doubt this is actually what you are trying to accomplish:

```
<div class="test">
</div>

.test:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://i1112.photobucket.com/albums/k497/animalsbeingdicks/abd-318.gif);
  width: 352px;
  height: 263px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/imurah/1/

Comment: Do you maybe have an image file of some sort that demonstrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you're right to doubt, this isn't what I'm trying to achieve. I've added a bit more context + a live development. If pictures would help I'll try and produce some.

Comment: That's not a bad solution, robtarr. The image could be placed in the background with a negative z-index.